# Examine for convergence $\sum\limits_{1}^{\infty}{(-1)^k\sin{\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The task is to examine $\sum\limits_{1}^{\infty}{(-1)^k\sin{\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}}}$ for convergence. First of all, $\sum\limits_{1}^{\infty}{|(-1)^k\sin{\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}}|}=\sum\limits_{1}^{\infty}{|\sin{\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}}|}=\sum\limits_{1}^{\infty}{|\sin{\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\frac{\sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{k}}}|}\sim\sum\limits_{1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}}$ - diverges, therefore the series is not absolutely convergent. Now, I obviously need to use Leibnitz' criteria to examine the series for conditional convergence. Obviously, $a_n=\sin{\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}}\to0$ as $k\to\infty$. But how can I prove that $a_n\geq a_{n+1}$ i.e. $\sin{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}\geq\sin{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}}}$, so that the criteria is met?

Comment: $\sin$ is sometimes a monotone function

Comment: Use the monotonicity of the sine function on $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\sin'(x)>0$ in $\left(0,\frac\pi2\right)$, $\sin$ is strictly increasing there. Therefore, and since $\frac1{\sqrt{k+1}}<\frac1{\sqrt k}$, $\sin\left(\frac1{\sqrt{k+1}}\right)<\sin\left(\frac1{\sqrt k}\right)$.